# Compare password in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

For compare password, I am using rxwebvalidators and it is working fine when I enter the value in password field after that confirmPassword field. If the confirmPassword field value is incorrect while entering the text then the FormControl become invalid.

But the problem is if the both controls have same value and I change the value in password field then confirmPassword field will not be invalid. But in actual case It must be invalid.

I tried in my local project and also create a small replica on stackblitz for you reference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nriznm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I do the following:

```js
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      password:[''],
      confirmPassword:['',RxwebValidators.compare({fieldName:'password'})]
    })
```

Below is my html code :

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
 password <input type="text" formControlName="password"/><br/>
  compare password <input type="text" formControlName="confirmPassword"/>
  {{userForm.controls.confirmPassword.errors | json}}
</form>
```

I have spend more than hour to identify the cause, but no success. Please help where I am doing wrong. It's working on rxweb.io site :  https://rxweb.io/form-validations/compare/validators#basiccomparevalidation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is working, I forgot to import 'RxReactiveFormsModule' in main module.

Register code of 'RxReactiveFormsModule' in main module:

```js
import { RxReactiveFormsModule } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,RxReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

working on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nriznm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts